# Appending angular directives to the DOM after document is already loaded doesn't work with ngAnimate

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

I am working on creating an Angular service that will append a simple notification box to the DOM and display it, without having to add HTML code and write the logic to hide and show it when necessary.

The service is called $notify and is used as below:

```
$notify.error( "this is an error", {position: "bottom-left"} );
```

The service will use angular.element to build the notification box and add it to the DOM. All of this works great.  However, I am also using ngAnimate and animate.css to have the notification smoothly slide in on show and slide out upon closing. I've verified that the animations work if I simply paste the notification HTML code into my page but will not work when the code is added dynamically via the service.  Do items have to be in the DOM at document load for ngAnimate to work? I've verified that the Angular service is loaded and properly inserting the HTML code but no animations are being applied. Here's what the HTML and CSS look like.

HTML:

```
<div class="simple-notify simple-notify-top-left simple-notify-info" ng-if="toggle">
    <simple-notify-header>Hello!<span class='simple-notify-dismiss pull-right' ng-click='doSomething()'>&times;</span></simple-notify-header>
    <simple-notify-body>Some bogus text here!</simple-notify-body>
</div>
```

CSS/LESS:

```
.simple-notify {
    &.ng-enter {
        display:none;
        animation: @animate-enter @animation-length;
        -webkit-animation: @animate-enter @animation-length;
    }
    &.ng-enter-active {
        display:block;
    }
    &.ng-leave {
        animation: @animate-leave @animation-length;
        -webkit-animation: @animate-leave @animation-length;
    }
}
```

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should never modify elements on the page from a service, this is what a directive is for. You should create an attribute directive on your `body` HTML element and in that place your logic. You can use `$rootScope.$broadcast` from your `$notify` service and `$scope.$on` in your directive. Alternatively, you can scrap the `$notify` service altogether and just use `$rootScope.$broadcast` as it can accept as many arguments as you want.

Lastly, you'll need to use the `$compile` service to make your HTML run properly after you've added it to the body. The `$compile` is what turns raw DOM into code Angular will process.

From inside your directive's `scope.$on` handler in the link function, you'd have something like.
`$compile('<div>template code here</div>')(scope, function(cloned, scope){
   element.append(cloned); 
});`

But you'd also need a cleanup as well. You might just add the code once as the directive's template and show/hide it with different content instead of adding/removing the DOM.